# Unable to type using the Java Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, typing

So I just started teaching myself Java yesterday, and in my infinite boredom decided to test the little that I know and am trying to make a simple text based game. I'm using the scanner to ask the player what class he would like to be, but when I run the code, I am unable to type anything whatsoever.
Here is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mainscript {
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Welcome to your first quest, young lord.");
    System.out.println("In this quest, you will face many foes.");
    System.out.println("What type of warrior are you, Sire?");
    System.out.println("[use propper caps](Warrior, Rogue, Mage, Brute)");
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner Warrior = null;
        Scanner Rogue = null;
        Scanner Mage = null;
        if (c == Warrior){//c = class
            System.out.println("So you are a warrior.");
            System.out.println("You come equipped with the following items.");
            System.out.println("Sword(20), Shield(10), Gold(20), and 50 points of health.");
            System.out.println("Defeat enemies and do side quests to earn more money for items.");
            int Sword, Shield, Health, Money;
            Sword = 20;
            Shield = 10;
            Health = 50;
            Money = 20;
        }else if(c == Rogue){ 
            System.out.println("So you are a Rogue.");
            System.out.println("You are equipped with the following items.");
            System.out.println("Dagger(20), Gloves(50), Buckler(10), Gold(20) and 40 points of health");
            System.out.println("Defeat enemies and do side quests to earn more money for items.");
            System.out.println("Alternately, use your Gloves to steal gold from your enemies in combat.");
            int Dagger, Gloves, Buckler, Money, Health;
            Dagger = 20;
            Gloves = 50;
            Buckler = 20;
            Money = 20;
            Health = 40;
        }else if(c == Mage){
            System.out.println("So you are a Mage.");
            System.out.println("You are equipped with the following items.");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Defeat enemies and do side quests to earn more money for items.");
            int Knife, Mana, Health;
        } 

}
}
```

I am simply wondering why I am unable to type anything when I run the code in Eclipse. Again, I am extremely new to programming so if you can answer accordingly so I can understand my mistake, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Firstly, where is **javascript**?? Secondly, please go through the [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-tips/examples-introductory/console/console-input-scanner.shtml) for scanner. This should help you out.

Comment: Yep, Java != JavaScript as they are two completely different animals.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

```
Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner Warrior = null;
Scanner Rogue = null;
Scanner Mage = null;
if (c == Warrior){
  //....
```

This is not how the Scanner class works. Your code will need only *one* Scanner object, and will need to call methods on this object, such as the `nextLine()` method, to get input from the user. Have a look at the tutorials including the [Scanner Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) before using new tools as it will help get you up to speed quickly. The compiler and the JVM are unforgiving and won't allow you to make up code and pray that it works.

i.e.,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String userInput = scan.nextLine();
if ("Warrior".equals(userInput)) {
   // do something
}
```